# Extending an operator from $C([0,1])$ to $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Suppose I have a "time-sampling" operator given by
\begin{align*}
S_m: C([0,1]) &\to \mathbb{R}^m \\
f &\mapsto (f(t_1),f(t_2),...,f(t_m))
\end{align*}

Now I want to extend this to $L^2([0,1])$. However, what would happen to the operator if the function was discontinuous exactly at the points $t_i$? For example, consider some piecewise-constant function $f$, whose discontinuities lie exactly at the points $t_i$. Is there a natural way to define what should $f(t_i)$ be?

If such an extension is impossible, then my "gut feeling" says that, at least for piecewise-continuous functions (which is the main case I'm considering), if $f$ has discontinuities at $t_i$, then I should take
\begin{equation*}
f(t_i) = \frac{f^+(t_i)+f^-(t_i)}{2}
\end{equation*}
where $f^+(t_i)$ and $f^-(t_i)$ are the one-sided limits. This feeling is based on Fourier series behavior at such discontinuities. But that's it, at most a feeling.

Comment: There is no natural way to evaluate $L^2$ classes at points. In part one can say that this is because the evaluation maps $ev_x : C([0,1])\to\Bbb R, f\mapsto f(x)$ ($x$ a fixed  point in $[0,1]$) are not continuous if you give $C([0,1])$ the topology given by the $\|f\|_p:=\sqrt[p]{\int |f|^p}$.

Comment: Usually we don't extend such an operator, but work with it as a densely defined unbounded operator.

Comment: More fundamentally, $L^2$ classes aren't functions, and indeed for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and any $L^2$ class $F$, there is some $f \in F$ such that $f(x) = y$.

Comment: As the other said, there is no natural way to do such extension, however I'd really like to know more context.

Comment: The context was a numerical method using Haar wavelets. Given a $L^2([0,1])$ function $f$, it can be represented as a wavelet series. Given its time samples, one can use the Haar transform to approximately get the Haar wavelet coefficients. I was studying how the higher-resolution (can be thought as higher frequency) terms behave under this approximation.